# CSS refactoring animated divs

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a large amount of code for something relatively simple, a short animation found in a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ER287/3/), but I'm disappointed with the code I've written. I feel it could be, or at least should be, a lot shorter because of how many times I've had to repeat myself to do something ever so slightly different:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="movement">
    <div class="mover x1 back"></div>
    <div class="mover x2 front"></div>
    <div class="mover x3 back"></div>
    <div class="mover x4 front"></div>
    <div class="mover x5 back"></div>
    <div class="mover x6 front"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mover {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 20px;
    background: black;

    -webkit-animation: animato 18s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: animato 18s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: animato 18s linear infinite;
    animation: animato 18s linear infinite;
}

...

.x1 {
    right: 30%;
    top: 90px;

    -webkit-animation-delay: -3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: -3s;
    -o-animation-delay: -3s;
    animation-delay: -3s;
}
.x2 {
    right: 45%;
    top: 130px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
    -o-transform: scale(0.6);
    transform: scale(0.6);
    opacity: 0.6; 

    -webkit-animation-delay: -6s; 
    -moz-animation-delay: -6s;
    -o-animation-delay: -6s;
    animation-delay: -6s;
}

... for each and every moving object, up to x6
```

What I'd really like to do is have just the one container div (class="movement" in the HTML above) with no child div tags in which I can create 6 moving objects scrolling by. Also to not have to repeat -vendor-animation-delay or -vendor-transform just to change the delay time/scale for each rule would be fantastic. Is there a better refactor of my code that I've missed, or will I really have to repeat this on each and every div to achieve this effect using CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much you can do, except for using a preprocessor like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [less](http://lesscss.org/), which allow you to shorten your css (sass example):

```
@mixin prefixes($declaration,$value){
    -webkit-#{$declaration}:$value;
    -moz-#{$declaration}:$value;
    -o-#{$declaration}:$value;
    #{$declaration}:$value;
}
@mixin animation-delay($delay){
    @include prefixes("animation-delay",$delay);
}
@mixin position($right,$top){
    right:$right;
    top:$top;
}
.x1 {
    @include position(30%,90px);
    @include animation-delay(-3s);
}
.x2 {
    @include position(45%,130px);
    @include animation-delay(-6s);
    /* same is possible for the transform, etc. */
}
```

I would show you an example in fiddle (actually you can use sass there: Languages -> switch CSS -> SCSS) but unfortunately the sass option seems to be broken.

The less/sass sources are definitely easier to maintain, but in the end of course it compiles to your original verbose CSS.

Comment: The more I'm on SO, the more I'm seeing how much more versatile OOCSS is vs CSS. This is a much more manageable alternative - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/).

Quoting from the Animate.css site:

> animate.css is a bunch of cool, fun, and cross-browser animations for you to use in your projects. Great for emphasis, home pages, sliders, and general just-add-water-awesomeness.